# Snap scroll is breaking jQuery fade in

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade

I'm having an issue with two separate features I'm trying to use. Firstly, I'm using some jQuery to have content fade in once it enters the browser window, and secondly I'm using snap scroll in CSS.

I've got both of these features working on their own, however, when I try to run both together it seems that the scroll snap is breaking the fade in. I think this is something to do with overflows possibly, but I'm already slightly out of my depth with the jQuery here, so unsure how (if?) to get around this issue??

Here's my current code...

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
    $(".fade").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      
      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
      } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
      }
    });
  }).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.snap-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.snap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-stop: normal;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  transition: 300ms all ease-in-out;
}

.snap:nth-child(1) {background: lightpink;}.snap:nth-child(2) {background:lightgreen;}.snap:nth-child(3) {background: lightblue;}.snap:nth-child(4) {background: lightyellow;}

.fade {
 opacity: 1;
  transition: 300ms all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snap-scroll-wrapper">
  <div class="snap">
    <code class="fade">Some text here</code>
  </div>
  <div class="snap">
    <code class="fade">Some text here</code>
  </div>
  <div class="snap">
    <code class="fade">Some text here</code>
  </div>
  <div class="snap">
    <code class="fade">Some text here</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've searched for other people with the same issue, both on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but can't seem to find anyone with the exact (or even fairly close) issue, so decided to post my own question.

Any insight anyone can offer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use scroll event listener for this, try using Intersection Observer API. It is supported in every browser and it was designed to solve problems like this: when is an element overlapping with another element, with the viewport, stuff like this.

On [this site there is a good example](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/) on how to fade elements in once they get into viewport (scroll down to see it in action)

To use IO you first have to first set the options for it, then define which element(s) to watch and last to define what exactly happens once the IO triggers.

Here is a short example to get you started:

```js
const SELECTOR = '.watched';
const ANIMATE_CLASS_NAME = 'animated';

const animate = element => (
  element.classList.add(ANIMATE_CLASS_NAME)
);

const isAnimated = element => (
  element.classList.contains(ANIMATE_CLASS_NAME)
);

const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    
    // when element's is in viewport,
    // animate it!
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      animate(entry.target);
      // remove observer after animation
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
});

// get only these elements,
// which are not animated yet
const elements = [].filter.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR),
  element => !isAnimated(element, ANIMATE_CLASS_NAME)
);
//console.log(elements);

// start observing your elements
elements.forEach((element) => intersectionObserver.observe(element));
```

```css
.h100 {
height: 100vh;
}

.watched {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .5s;
}

.watched.animated {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="h100">
scroll down
</div>
<div class="watched">
I'm watched
</div>
<div class="h100">
Another element, keep scrolling
</div>
<div class="watched">
I'm also watched
</div>
```